# versioning each field vs history date field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Which do you recommend and why?

I have a few tables, when i make a change to the data... it should go to a history table (audit) with a effective date.

The other solution is versioning each field to insert a new row when making changes to the data?

Which is the best method for the invoice information? Item name and price is always change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension), `type 2` and `type 4`, appropriately.

Both methods are valid and may be more appropriate for your needs, depending on your model and query requirements.

Basically, `type 2` (versioning) is more appropriate when you need to query historical values as often as the current one, while `type 4` (history table) is more suited when you are querying the current value more often and there are more queries (more queries to develop I mean) against the most recent value.

Comment: I have an order_items to display past orders.. which one is better? The value of items name and price is always change.

Comment: @user: usually (usually) a history table is better, since you need the current price is more important and you run more queries against it. This way, you won't need to add a filter on `isActive` or a similar field to each query.

Comment: Instead of DATE in the history table, i added the version field. Example of tables: item.version, item_history.version and the order_table table will contain the version number. So I will get 100% accurate information rather than relaying on the date search.

Answer (score 2):

A system we use and happy with:
Each table that requires history, we create a similar table and adding a timestamp field at the end, which becomes a part of the PK.
Each update on original table, we insert into history table with the same conditions:

```
update table x WHERE somthing something

insert into table x_history 
select * from x WHERE something something
```

That keeps your data clean and your tables slim.

Comment: There is no problem with accuracy with this solution? For example.. Showing invoice data from the history table (old data).. I hope it show the correct price lol

Comment: Why should there be a problem? You can use versioning, but it involves more logic/code which I find not necessary

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference would be to user the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in your application and to implement a separate history table. This means that you can pull the data from the history table when you need it and you don't compromise the speed of querying the main table.